# Put transparent View with nested Text fields on MapBox map through react-native

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl

I am developing mobile app with react native.
In app there is case when we need to put transparent View with nested Text fields on a map.
As a map we are using Mapbox library.
Is it possible to do it so?